# What if the MVUE depends on the parameter?

Tags: estimation, frequentist, mse

The minimum variance, unbiased estimator $\hat \theta$ of $\theta$ is defined by
$$\hat \theta = \text{argmin}_{\hat \theta} \; \mathbb{E} \left( (\hat \theta - \theta)^2 \, | \, \theta\right), \quad \text{ subject to } \quad \mathbb{E} \left( \hat \theta \, | \, \theta\right)  - \theta = 0 $$
where the expectation, $\mathbb{E}$, is taken over the data, $Y$ (given the parameter $\theta$). This yields an expression for $\hat \theta$ in terms of $y$. I.e. $\hat \theta = \hat \theta (y)$. But if instead we obtain $\hat \theta = \hat \theta (y; \theta)$, what do we do then? As far as I can tell, there's nothing in the definition of MVUEs above that guarantees independence of $\hat \theta$ from $\theta$. One could achieve such independence by letting the expectation be over $\theta$ as well as the data $Y$. But this assumes that $\theta$ is a random variable, and then we're doing Bayesian inference. What if we have a strictly frequentist perspective?

For example, the ordinary least squares estimator, $(X'X)^{-1} X' \boldsymbol{y}$, is the BLUE (so the MVUE among linear, unbiased estimators) for the model $ \boldsymbol{Y} = X \boldsymbol{\theta} + \boldsymbol{\eta}$, and it does not have explicit dependence on $\theta$. Jolly good.
Unfortunately I can't think of a case where the expression for the MVUE does depend on the parameter, however, again, there is nothing apparent in the definition of MVUEs above that can guarantee this.

### Edit

If the requirement "for all $\theta$" is added the the definition of MVUEs (also called *uniform* MVUEs (UMVUEs), that implies that there is not dependence on the parameter itself in the expression of the estimator. However, UMVUEs may not exist. As I mention in the comments, it seems weird that a frequentist would completely have to abandon the MVUE criterion in these "degenerate" cases, while a Bayesian could easily make sense of them too by taking expectations over the parameter as well, instead of requiring uniform optimality.

Comment: Where does this "definition" of MVUE come from and how is it related to [conventional definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-variance_unbiased_estimator#Definition), where your question simply does not arise?

Comment: It is the same as the definition on the wiki page you link to, except that the wiki page discusses *uniformly* MVUEs. I.e. UMVUEs are the MVUEs for any theta, which implies that their formula does not explicitly depend on theta. The article doesn't take the existence of UMVUEs for granted, however, which I think means that in some cases one does indeed obtain an MVUE that does depend on theta. So it seems that a frequentist would then be at an impasse, and would have to use some other criterion for deriving some optimal estimator.

Comment: If it's an MVUE then *by definition* it cannot depend on $\theta$ (no estimator can): that's why I'm lost here.

Comment: Yes, I agree. It cannot. However, its definition, without the *uniform* bit, does not guarantee this. (And I insist again that my definition is the same as the "conventional one".) Which implies that its existence, is not guaranteed. 

It seems weird then that a frequentist would completely have to abandon the MVUE criterion in these "degenerate" cases, while a Bayesian could easily make sense of them too by taking expectations over the parameter as well.

Comment: @whuber, I'm asking this question because I'm looking for conditions under which Bayesian (with a flat prior) and frequentist point estimators, derived as optimisers of expected losses, coincide. Do you happen to know any references on this?

Comment: Maybe *that's* the question you should be asking, Patrick! In the meantime, check out the results of a search on [frequentist Bayesian estimator](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=frequentist+bayesian+estimator).